# How to work with continue in a while loop with except AssertionError in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, except

Hi guys I need some help here.

I'm working on this exercise. What I need and what is going on?

When I get into **except ValueError** the loop back to the beginning, I do not, necessarily, need to write **continue** to it happens, OK(It is what a desire).

But when I get into **except AssertionError**, not matter if I write to **continue**, the loop just stops and that is the problem. I need that my loop back to the beginning when I get into the **except AssertionError**.

*Could you help me?*

```
prompt="\nWould you like to get a ticket?"  
prompt+="\nPlease write your age: "

age= 0    
while age >= 0:


try:       
    age=int(input(prompt))
    assert age > 0             
  
except ValueError:
    print(f"This option is not valid. You need to input an integer number. Try it again.")
   
    
except AssertionError: 
    print("Wow that can't be possible!! Try it again")
    continue
        
           
else:      
    
                
    if age >= 0 and age <3:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket is free!")
        break        
        
    elif age >=3 and age<=12:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket price is $10.")
        break 
        
    elif age > 75 and age <121:        
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket price is $7.")
        break
   
    else:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket price is $15.")
        break
  
finally:
    print("Fim da execução")
```

==============

**Output**

Would you like to get a ticket?
Please write your age: one
This option is not valid. You need to input an integer number. Try it again.
Fim da execução

Would you like to get a ticket?
Please write your age: -45
Wow that can't be possible!! Try it again
Fim da execução

==============

**Here my loop stops**
But I need that it ask me again:

*Would you like to get a ticket?

Please write your age:*

Comment: Assert is for sanity checks and should'nt be used directly on user input.

Comment: Just use simple `if` to do this check and then raise `ValueError` when it fails.

Comment: You should *never* use ``except AssertionError`` in regular code! Assertions can be partially disabled by running Python in ``-O`` mode, changing your program semantics. *Only* explicitly handle ``AssertionError`` when the code is about meta-programming via assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop termination condition was backwards, your use of `finally` seemed out of place, and you did need `continue` statements following your `except` blocks.  But, overall you were pretty close.  The example below fixes the problems you encountered, but tries to keep the overall logic the same as what you had.

Edit: Realized that you were using `break` after each case you successfully handle, so no need use an age-based `while` loop condition.

Example:

```
prompt="\nWould you like to get a ticket?"
prompt+="\nPlease write your age: "

while True:

    try:       
        age = int(input(prompt))
        assert age > 0             
  
    except ValueError:
        print(f"This option is not valid. You need to input an integer number. Try it again.")
        continue

    except AssertionError: 
        print("Wow that can't be possible!! Try it again")
        continue
                    
    if age >= 0 and age <3:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket is free!")
        break        
        
    elif age >=3 and age<=12:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket price is $10.")
        break 
        
    elif age > 75 and age <121:        
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket price is $7.")
        break
   
    else:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, your ticket price is $15.")
        break
  
print("Fim da execução")
```

Output:

```
Would you like to get a ticket?
Please write your age:  one
This option is not valid. You need to input an integer number. Try it again.

Would you like to get a ticket?
Please write your age:  -45
Wow that can't be possible!! Try it again

Would you like to get a ticket?
Please write your age:  10
You are 10 years old, your ticket price is $10.
Fim da execução
```